# Openstack Swift stat [Errno 111] Connection refused

Tags: openstack, swift

when i type

```
swift stat
```

i get this error :

```
HTTPConnectionPool(host='controller', port=8080): Max retries exceeded
with url: /v1/AUTH_d17698cf7bbf4dcc8fc59ed6f7b48052 (Caused by 
NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 
0x7f1c597f9910>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] 
Connection refused'))
```

Answer (score 0):

"connection refused" means either that a firewall is actively refusing access to port 8080 on `controller`, or that no process is listening at that port.

In the latter case, your Swift proxy server is either not running or configured to listen at a different port than 8080.

Comment: thank you for the quick reply no it's not a firewall issue cuz i turned off the firewall and same problem right now the error i'm facing when i run swift stat is :
Account HEAD failed: http://controller:8080/v1/AUTH_65ae04ae54ac4087853771c38b0ec542 503 Service Unavailable
Failed Transaction ID: tx893fee0fa3ca4b0aa85ba-006032b38a

Comment: This is not the same problem. What changed between the first and the second error message? Check the Swift logs; the transaction ID is convenient for finding relevant messages. Perhaps the account server is not running.

Comment: the problem was in the pipeline in the /etc/swift/proxy-server.conf soo now the error now is 503 Service Unavailable Failed when i type swift stat and there's no indication in the logs at all

Comment: If not in the Swift logs, perhaps the web server's.

Comment: where can i find that exactly ?

Comment: Depends on your configuration. `/var/log` is commonly used, but it can be anywhere.

Comment: thank you but still didn't find a solution the log just repeat the same ligne : 
503 Service Unavailable Failed

Comment: Seems like the web server can't communicate with Swift's proxy server?

Comment: Yes i think so too what should i do ?

Comment: First, find out how the connection between webserver and proxy server is configured.